# How to populate php html tables with different data for users and admin

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, datatable, populate

Can someone teach me how to populate this table with different data from same sql table but result will be session user wise but admin will get merged result , below code IS CORRECT BUT THE PROBLEM IS ADMIN CANT GET USER DATA IN THE TABLE ; 
IS THERE ANY WAY TO IMPLEMENT 
`$select = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_invoice WHERE created_by = '".$_SESSION['user_id']."'  ORDER BY invoice_id DESC");` FOR USER AND `$select = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_invoice ORDER BY invoice_id DESC");` FOR ADMIN. [PAGE AND TABLE WILL BE SAME]

```
<tbody>
                        <?php
                        $no = 1;
                        $select = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_invoice WHERE created_by = '".$_SESSION['user_id']."'  ORDER BY invoice_id DESC");
                        $select->execute();
                        while($row=$select->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
                        ?>
```

Comment: Why not just do the second query if the user is admin? That will contain all data anyways. Something like (pseudo code) `if ($_SESSION[’user’]==admin) { $select = [SELECT ALL QUERY] } else { $select = [SELECT WHERE CREATED BY QUERY] }`

Comment: If you are going to use a prepared statement,  use a placeholder too (`?`) and pass the data to the `execute()` call.